# Can't run MSTest unit tests via Resharper after upgrading to VS 2012 Update 2

Tags: visual-studio-2012, resharper

All tests are in pending state. I can not run or debug them. I see that others are experienced the same issue: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-339546

Comment: I'm using Resharper 8 beta, vs2012, and Typemock and I'm still having this issue. Anyone actually find a fix for this?

Answer (score 17):

Jetbrains are on the case already:

> We will be releasing an update to ReSharper 7 to fix the issue with the test runner and Visual Studio Update Pack 2.
>
> — JetBrains ReSharper (@resharper) [April 5, 2013](https://twitter.com/resharper/status/320154098211094529)

Comment: Jetbrains have now released a fix: http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2013/04/resharper-713-is-available-for-visual-studio-2012-update-2/

Comment: Still seeing this in Resharper 7 and 8/beta

Answer (score 4):

Jetbrains fix it: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-339987

Seems to work in most case, still not with Windows Phone.

Answer (score 1):

Run VS as administrator. I had exactly the same issue with vs2012 and resharper and it works like charm now

Answer (score 1):

I'm using ReSharper 8.0.2 and VS 2012 and had this issue. I downloaded VS2012 Update 3 from here: http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/visual-studio-update and it solved the issue