# ReSharper doesn't run MSTests in a new project

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, resharper, mstest

I forked LINQToCSV in GitHub to make a few changes.

When I tried running the unit tests using ReSharper, it never runs. The green spin keeps loading and loading, like this:

[image]

However, if I use the Test Explorer integrated in Visual Studio, they run fine.

I tried cleaning the solution and rebuilding again, and nothing...

Is there something specific I have to do?

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Resharper do you use?

There was a problem with **Resharper 7.1.2** and **VS2012 Update 2** with running Unittests.

See Jetbrains blog [http://blog.jetbrains.com/...](http://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2013/04/12/resharper-713-is-available-for-visual-studio-2012-update-2/)

Jetbrains issue tracker http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-339987

And Stackoverflow post [https://stackoverflow.com/...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15838499/1108036)

Comment: I'm currently using ReSharper 8.0.1000.2286 and Visual Studio 2012